# AngularJS - make model variable available to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am just starting with AngularJS and am trying to figure out how to easily reference (bind?) scope variables from outside the Angular controller.

Simple code:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourNameInput" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <input type="button" onClick="console.log(inputName);">
  <hr>
  <h1 ng-bind-template="Hello, {{yourNameInput}}"></h1>
</div>
```

How would I bind `{{yourNameInput}}` to `inputName` var that will be available to the rest of my application? There's one ugly way I managed to do that:

```
$scope.change = function() { inputName = $scope.yourNameInput; }
```

and then:

```
<... ng-change = "change()">
```

Anything more elegant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject [$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window) into your controller and make it available on the scope. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7T55/1/).

```
function Ctrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.window = $window;
}​
```

...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourNameInput" placeholder="Enter a name here" ng-change="window.yourName = yourNameInput">
```

For broader use you can make it available on the [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope). See another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7T55/2/).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .run(function($rootScope, $window){
        $rootScope.window = $window;
    });
```

Also you can see [Call Angular JS from legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code/10508731#10508731).

For console.log() you can use

```
<input type="button" onClick="console.log('{{yourNameInput}}');" value="Log">
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z7T55/).

If you want to debug AngularJS application you can use [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) ([textual description and source code](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang))

Comment: Thanks. All of those examples worked. If I could only figure out how to use jQuery validation now w/AngularJS, everything would be great.

Comment: @MarkL you could try using AngularUI which provides an alternate way to perform form validation http://angular-ui.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you wouldn't expect your outside world would update automatically when your model changes. Rather, you may do a pull to your model.

I don't like the idea of syncing your model data with a global variable. If I were you, I'd do this

```
console.log($("[ng-controller=Ctrl]").scope().yourNameInput);
```

which every place in the outside world is required to have access to the model.