# How to push data from non-AngularJS to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data that I am retrieving outside of AngularJS scope. I want to use this data to update the model inside Angular so that it reflects in the views as well, and thereafter work like how Angular should work. How do I push this data in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Angular JS from legacy code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope). From that page:

> **$apply()** is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that worked. Found more information on usage here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code

Comment: You may be able to go more efficient (if you wish) by doing a $compile.

Comment: Specifically, if it's html data, you can call $compile on your injected html and linking that to your scope.  Check out this video (starting at 39:05): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB7hfvqyZpg