# Using Angularjs $http in browser console

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've testing AngularJS services in browser console during development for quick verification. The way I inject a service into console is as describe in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529185/605840) or

```
var $inj = angular.injector(['myApp']);
var serv = $inj.get('myService');
serv.doSomething();
```

That was working perfectly with AngularJS 1.0.7. However, after upgrading to 1.1.5, it doesn't work anymore for services that uses `$http` service, that no xhr will be sent.

I've tested injecting `$http` directly, it also doesn't work. AngularJS changelog seems to have no record on this issue. May I know what's the problem here?

**Update:**

<del>It seems like AngularJS 1.0.7 Uncompressed version doesn't work as well. Currently the tested working version is only AngularJS 1.0.7 Minified.</del>

It works for Uncompressed also.

Comment: Does it work if you get access to the `$rootScope` service and call `$rootScope.$apply()` ? I ran into a sort-of-similar issue the other day, and kicking off a digest cycle was the fix.

Comment: @BrandonTilley That works fantastically! So is`$http` changed to be like `$q` that will only be resolved in a digest cycle? I think I should read the changelog more closely. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think so. I thought maybe I had imagined it working without a digest cycle, but you've helped me realize I'm not out of my mind (at least not because of this. :)

Comment: @BrandonTilley Me too thought it will work without a digest cycle, at least not for sending xhr. :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http');
```

then

```
$http.get(...) // or post or whatever
```

Comment: Loved that! I even don't know why the person who asked doesn't assign that as a correct answer!

Comment: ah damn that's awesome! We've got Marketeers using Optimizely to run AB tests and now there's no need to include heavy jQuery too!!