# Calling Angular service from outside JS via .scope().call() hangs request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-plus

I'm working on adding a Google+ signin button to my Angular app and most of it is working, except for the handling of the callback result. The callback from the G+ signin is an outside JS function called `signinCallback` with looks like so:

```
//Handling the Google+ Signin right here
function signinCallback(authResult) {
angular.element($("#btnGooglePlus")).scope().handleGoogleSignin(authResult);
}
```

The only way I could figure out how to pass the `authResult` back into the controller was to call a controller method via `element.scope()`. `handleGoogleSignin` is called fine, and inside that function there is a `http.get` service call that looks like:

```
User.getSocialKey(key).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

`User` is a service, and `getSocialKey` looks like:

```
getSocialKey: function(etag) {
    console.log("Hit the social key service with the etag: " + etag);
    return $http({
        url: '/api/user/social',
        method: 'post',
        data: {etag:etag}
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log("Returning promise from social service");
        return result.data;
    });
},
```

The first log statement gets hit fine, then nothing. Request is never sent. Now, if I go and click something on the page that has an `ng-model` attribute (example, a checkbox), the request is then sent and received just fine. So my question: **Why is my Angular service call being suspended until I click on something? Why isn't it going through right away?**

I've tried replacing `getSocialKey` with working service calls, same thing. I believe the issue comes down to calling the function with `angular.element($("#btnGooglePlus")).scope().handleGoogleSignin(authResult);` but I'm not sure. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I can't test but I think you should call `.$apply()` since the action is triggered outside the AngularJS's scope.

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    angular.element($("#btnGooglePlus")).scope().handleGoogleSignin(authResult);
    angular.element($("#btnGooglePlus")).scope().$apply();
}
```

Comment: This seems right; see also the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436385/using-angularjs-http-in-browser-console#comment27422351_18436385

Comment: Hmm, that's throwing a `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'` error. So, I think the problem is because a `$digest` cycle is never started, so the request just get stalled. So far I'm able to solve the problem by calling `$scope.$digest()` in my `handleGoogleSignin` method in the controller. Is this right? Seems sloppy.

Comment: Small mistake: it is `$apply()`, not `apply()`, but otherwise this should be the solution.

Comment: @sza -- Ill give this a try once I'm back home... few hours or so. Will update then.

Comment: Still no go, the `$digest` cycle still isn't started. I read about possibly wrapping this in a `$timeout` call, but shouldn't `$apply` take care of that?

Comment: @tymeJV Hmm...weird. :(

Comment: Yeah... so far, calling that `$digest` manually has taken care of it. Not the prettiest solution but ill take it for now. Either way, +1 for the effort and thanks for the help so far.