# How do I remove some javascript during grunt-usemin compilation

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have code that makes it easy and fast to write/test code, that code does not belong in my production code (mostly it mocks out the server so I only need the grunt server).

Two parts to this, one is how to I remove parts of a script

```
angular.module('nglaborcallApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute',
'server_mocks',  // Don't want this line in the production build
'dialogs'
```

]

and then a section of index.html that needs to go away

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/mocks/mocks.js -->
<script type='text/javascript'>var Mocks = {};</script>
<script src='scripts/mocks/jobs.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/mock.js'></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

So this might be 2 questions.   I don't see anything in the usemin documentation about this so I'm guessing there is some other tool, but I don't know what the name of that tool is.

The other possibility is I'm doing it wrong and rather than inject this mocking object, I should be doing it with the grunt server.  What is everyone else doing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, so stumbled on the answer while looking for something else and since no one had yet responded.  Here is how I solved it:

You get a copy of **[Grunt Preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess#getting-started)** with

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-preprocess
```

Then you modify your `GruntFile.js` like so (this is for an angular project, YMMV)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');      <-- Add this line near the top of the file
```

add this in your list of subtasks

```
    preprocess : {
        options: {
            inline: true,
            context : {
                DEBUG: false
            }
        },
        html : {
            src : [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html', 
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/*.html'
            ]
        },
        js : {
            src: '.tmp/concat/scripts/*.js'
        }
    },
```

Modify your registered tasks (at the bottom of the file) like thils:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'preprocess:js',  // Remove DEBUG code from production builds
    'preprocess:html',  // Remove DEBUG code from production builds
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
]);
```

Then modify your existing javascript code something like this:

```
// @if DEBUG
'server_mocks',  // Won't be included in production builds
// @endif
```

and your existing html code something like this:

```
<!-- @if DEBUG -->
<script src='scripts/mock.js'></script>  <!-- Won't be included in production builds -->
<!-- @endif -->
```

Comment: Try using the `remove` type like in [processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml) in `index.html`

Comment: @SamSimmons That will only process .html, not .js

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at dom munger (https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger) you can give the elements that you want removed a specific attribute or IDs and have it remove them from the html file.  But, what I like better is to have it inject, via append or prepend, the unwanted element when I specify a target of dev.  It keeps the original HTML cleaner.  I haven't delt with removing portions of javascript though.  Depending on what else is in your js file that you want changed, you could have it inject a different version of the file for your dev and release build.

Remove Examples:

- 'script[data-remove="true"]' - all script elements with the attribute data-remove and a value of true.
- '#removeMe' - the element with the ID removeMe

Append Examples:

- { selector:'html',html:'<script src=\'scripts/mock.js\'></script>
  ' } - append the specified html to the html element

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution where you don't need extra tools:

as stated in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-usemin#blocks) you could use a type which is not css/js and this will be removed during build

```
<!-- build:<type>(alternate search path) <path> -->
... HTML Markup, list of script / link tags.
<!-- endbuild -->
```

- type: can be js, css or a custom type with a block replacement function defined
- If another type, the block will be ignored. Useful for "development only" blocks that won't appear in your build

so you can just do something like this:

```
<!-- build:mockJs -->
<script type='text/javascript'>var Mocks = {};</script>
<script src='scripts/mocks/jobs.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/mock.js'></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**EDIT**: for javascript you could use uglifies global definition

http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/docs/uglify-examples.md#conditional-compilation

just do an uglify config in you gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
   ...
   uglify: { 
      options: { 
         compress: {
            global_defs: {
               "PROD": true
             }
         }
      }
   }
   ...
});
```

and in js do something like:

```
var modules = ['ngCookies', 'ngResource',
   'ngSanitize',
   'ngRoute',
   'dialogs'
]

if(!PROD) {
  modules.push('server_mocks');
}

angular.module('nglaborcallApp', modules);
```

---

you could also add this global JS in your debug block

```
<!-- build:mockJs -->
<script type='text/javascript'>var Mocks = {};</script>
<script src='scripts/mocks/jobs.js'></script>
<script src='scripts/mock.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   PROD = false;
</script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside a JS script file though, only in the HTML.  The question was about removing JS code as well as html text.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a method to do the js part with the utilities inside usemin.