# Execute some angular code in the browser console

Tags: angularjs

I have a website builded with angular. I want to do some debugging in the browser console but i don't know how to actually execute my function.

I tried this :

```
angular.module('app').run(function(myService) {
    myService.doSomething();
});
```

But the function is not called.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527832/how-can-i-test-an-angularjs-service-from-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

This works - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DnEBXIcs9pHenvhbFXWv?p=preview)

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
  .run(function(myService) {
      myService.doSomething();
  })
  .factory('myService', function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.doSomething = function () {
      console.log("Hello world");
    }
    return obj;
  });
```