# can't get service instance from $injector.get()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I define a customer service named "greeting", but can't get the instance from $injector.get('greeting'). It will throw such error: *Unknown provider: greetingProvider <- greeting*. So which is the right way to get it? Following is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('myDI', []);
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.provider('greeting', function(){
        this.$get = function(){
             return function(name) {
                 console.log("Hello, " + name);
            };
        };
    });
});

var injector = angular.injector();
var greeting = injector.get('greeting');
greeting('Ford Prefect');
```

Comment: You're asking an injector without passing any module. But your greeting service is defined in the myDI module. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.injector

Comment: Most importantly: why are you trying to use `injector` directly? It is very, very rare to play with it outside of a unit test... See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13400687/1418796

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to create the injector from the module.

```
var app = angular.module('myDI', []);
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.provider('greeting', function(){
        this.$get = function(){
             return function(name) {
                 console.log("Hello, " + name);
            };
        };
    });
});
var injector = angular.injector(['myDI', 'ng']); //Add this line
var greeting = injector.get('greeting');
greeting('Ford Prefect');
var injector = angular.injector();
```

Try it here. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vVV8H/1/)

Comment: it seems that angular.injector(['myDI']) also works fine, not need 'ng'

Comment: @jason Good to know. I haven't tried that. But the point is to make sure to get the provider from the save module.

Comment: This stopped working in angular 1.3.X

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9692

Comment: Seems to work if I switch the order of the dependencies: `['ng', 'myDI']`