# can't get service instance from $injector.get() with dependencies

Tags: jquery, angularjs

My question is an extension of asked question link is given below

[can't get service instance from $injector.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897548/cant-get-service-instance-from-injector-get)

```
var app = angular.module('myDI', []);
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.provider('greeting',function(){
        this.$get = function(){
             return function(name) {
                 console.log("Hello, " + name);
            };
        };
    });
});
```

we can get Service instance using below code.

```
var injector = angular.injector(['myDI', 'ng']); //Add this line
var greeting = injector.get('greeting');
greeting('Ford Prefect');
var injector = angular.injector();
```

But if I add dependencies in Service like...

```
var app = angular.module('myDI', []);
    app.config(function($provide){
        $provide.provider('greeting',['$http','$q' function($http,$q){
            this.$get = function(){
                 return function(name) {
                     console.log("Hello, " + name);
                };
            };
        });
    });
```

how we will get an instance of service using the angular injector.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Many things in here:

- you can't inject services at provider definition level. They depend only on what is defined with angular.const and angular.config (and maybe something more, I don't remember anymore). So you can't inject $http or $q this way.
- if you want to inject services in yoru service, you must inject them at the factory definition level (the $get)
- to make it simplier don't define your provider in your config
- $http or $q are not in the default module. To access these services, you must import the 'ng' module that contains it.

Here is the corrected, on which I added a way to configure your provider.
you can access it on this plunker: http://jsbin.com/yajomecoxi/edit?js,console

```
var app = angular.module('myDI', ['ng']);

app.provider('greeting',function(){
  var greetingToUser="Hello, ";
  this.setGreeting=function(greet){
    greetingToUser=greet;
  }
  this.$get = ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return function(name) {
      console.log(greetingToUser + name);
    };
  }];
});


app.config(['greetingProvider',function(greetingProvider){
  greetingProvider.setGreeting("welcome to you ");
}])


var $injector = angular.injector(['myDI']);
var greeting = $injector.get('greeting');
greeting("sfgsdfg");
```

see more information on these links:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: You are right it was factory level not provider.Please tell me how can i access instnace of service.

Comment: everything is in the working sample I gave!!! Moreover you have to full working example on plunker. Basically, you create the injector by mentioning modules where candidate injections will be scanned, and you make a get on it... basically like you did. One more thing, there was couple of js syntax mistakes in your code, I corrected them, but I believe it was just because you quickly wrote it.

Comment: I found the solution here...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319784/call-angularjs-service-from-simple-js-code