# Error when using angular.injector() within a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to create a service in angular and within it, to get a service using angular's `$injector.get(...)`. 
(I know I can inject it, but I want to create it manually).

For some reason, I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
>   `$rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $urlRouter <- $state <- $location`

```js
(function () {
    var $injector = angular.injector(["myApp"]);//Here is where I get the error
    var myService= $injector.get("myService");

    var pseudoService = function(){
        var service = myService;
        return{
            service:service
        }
    }

    app.factory("pseudoService", pseudoService);
}(angular));
```

Here is a plunker I made. 
I hope it demonstrates the issue precisely.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2IbChnCoztMV6rONI2s9?p=preview)

Comment: Nothing is there in that plunker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't retrieve the injector from angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400687/cant-retrieve-the-injector-from-angular)

Answer (score 1):

See this plunker that contains your code in `app.js`

https://plnkr.co/edit/5VA5XgbNiCAX0ZcjDADo?p=preview

Now, its working fine.

You are writing `injector` code where the service is not available and you must add `ng` explixitly in the `angular.injector()` function, for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector. That is why you are getting the error

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'plunker']);
  var a = $injector.get('myService')
  console.log(a);
});

app.factory('pseudoService', pseudoService);

var pseudoService = function(){
    var service = myService;
    myService.sayHello();
    return{
     service:service
    }
}



var myService = function(){
  var sayHello = function(){
    alert("Hello")
  }
  return{
    sayHello:sayHello
  }
}

app.service('myService', myService);
```

Comment: it is defined, somewhere else in the code, and it represents a different service

Comment: Are you sure that the error shown is belongs to the code you provided? If not, provide that code. That is related to dependency injection

Comment: Did you using `ui.router` in your app?

Comment: the ui.router works fine. the problem is occuring only when I'm trying to use the angular.injector()

Comment: I added a plunker

Comment: Nothing is there in that plunker

Answer (score 1):

That question already have a great answer on SO

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403660/2204146

What you need is add 'ng' module first in your injector constructor

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'plunker']);
```