# Access Angular object's function from outside JS

Tags: javascript, scope, angularjs

I'm building a HTML-app with the AngularJS framework. I have some legacy JavaScript actions that needs to access a function within the Angular-object, and I can't get it to work.
This is the Angular-object (function I need to access is the `$scope.info()`):

```
function content($scope) {
    $scope.info = function (id) {
        console.log('Got a call from '+id);
        $scope.text = "Hello, "+id;
    };
}
```

I have attempted to access it through `angular.element('content').scope().info('me')`, but with no result (console says `undefined`). I attempted to dump the result of `angular.element('content').scope()`, and I got the full object list and everything. Theoretically, my first example should work, however it does not.

Any guidance as to how I can achieve this is much appreciated!
<sub><sup>(PS: [Call Angular JS from legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10490570/267892) did not resolve this).</sup></sub>

---

When I was finally able to access the function, it didn't work as expected – the value of `$scope.text` is *technically* modified, but the expressions used in the HTML are not updated! For example, `<p>{{text}}</p>`does not get updated after this function is called from an external function.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`angular.element()` expects a **DOM element**, so if you have this html:

```
<div ng-controller="content">
</div>
```

and you want to access its DOM element, use an id:

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-controller="content">
</div>
```

Then

```
angular.element($('#myDiv')).scope().info('me')
```

or without jQuery:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv')).scope().info('me')
```

should work.

**Edit:**

If you changed something on the scope, you will probably need to use [$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv')).scope().$apply();
```

Comment: That did work indeed! Though something unexpected happens: the function runs, but if I the function accesses one of the scope's expressions, it does not get updated in the controller.

Comment: Also, is there any reason this would return `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` when called within a function?

Comment: Do you have jQuery in your page?

Comment: if you don't have jquery, try angular.element(document.getElementById('#myDiv')).scope().info('me')

Comment: Ah, I don't have jQuery, no. For some reason, it does not work without jQuery, guess I'll have to implement it :)

Comment: There still is one problem however – the Angular-function's expressions are not updated if the function change their values when called from the outside. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ah, great! I'm really new to all of this, I am seriously building my first Angular website today. My first website in general really. Oh well, thank you so much!

Comment: @catwoman make sure you are doing `angular.element($('#myDiv')).scope().$apply();` and not `angular.element($('#myDiv')).scope().info('me').$apply();`

Comment: For the non jquery examples, there should be no hash in getElementById('#myDiv')

Comment: Thanks, I was missing controller declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was trying to access/set angular's values from a callback (in another Window); the solution was to use jQuery's `data` methods.  The `data` API allows you to attach object literals to DOM nodes.  So instead of resorting to something like global variables (which would also work), I just do something like:

```
/**
 * Listen to a global "lookupTemplate" event
 */
$j(document).on("lookupTemplate", function(event, template) {
        $j(document).data("template", template);
        window.open("/callbackURL", 'Callback Window', 'status=0,toolbar=0,height=230,width=358');
    });

/**
* Callback from other window, to change template ID and name (it's global)
* @param {String} template_id the ID for the selected template from the other window
* @param {String} template_name the name for the selected template from the other window
*/
function templateChosen(template_id, template_name) {
    var template = $(document).data("template");
    var appendedSelector = "[" + template.index + "]";
    $('[name="templateId' + appendedSelector + '"').val(template_id);
    $('[name="templateName' + appendedSelector + '"').val(template_name);
    // Update angular vars just in case
    template.id = template_id;
    template.name = template_name;
}

var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ActionsController", function($scope) {
        $scope.actions = [];
        $scope.lookupTemplate = function(index) {
            $scope.actions[index].template.index = index;
            $(document).trigger("lookupTemplate", $scope.actions[index].template);
        }
    }
);
```

Where I increment the `name` attribute of each new `action` with the `{{index}}` helper, included in Angular.