# Passing a twig variable to an Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, twig

I'm using Angular and Twig. Is there a way I can call an Angular function called initItems in my html like inside a

```
{% for post in posts%} //twig
    <% verbatim %>
       {{initItems(post)}}  //angular
    <% endverbatim %>
{% endfor %}
```

when post is a twig variable? Inside my initItems function in my controller, post is showing up as undefined.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298361/access-angular-objects-function-from-outside-js

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is first changing the start and end interpolation for AngularJS to something else like

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});
```

Now you can do combine it with your twig

```
{% for post in posts %} //twig
   <% verbatim %>
     {[{initItems( {{ post }} )}]}  //angular start with {[{ and end with }]}
   <% endverbatim %>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also check this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider) for more info