# accessing a variable in controller from an outside function (angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a chat page where messages are displayed through `ng-repeat` on the array `$scope.messages`

I am subscribed to a backend-as-a-service and use their api for sending instant messages. When a message is received, the `onChatMessage` is executed.

What I'd like to do is to push any messages received to the the `$scope.messages` array so that the chat page displays the newly received message. However I don't know how to access the `$scope.messages` array from my function. Is this possible?

my controller:

```
.controller('ChatCtrl',function($scope,$stateParams,$ionicScrollDelegate,$q,principal){

 $scope.messages = ["test message 1","test message2];

})
```

This function calls when a message is received:

```
function onChatMessage(senderID,message){
     // senderID, message are predefined by the api of my backend-as-a-service
     // I'd like to push the message received here to scope.messages 
     // but accessing $scope here leads to undefined error. 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Angular object's function from outside JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298361/access-angular-objects-function-from-outside-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

```
function onChatMessage() {
    var scope = angular.element(...get the element...).scope()
    // example, angular.element(document.body).scope();
    scope.messages.push()
    ....
    scope.$digest() // updates the watched expressions
                    // - hence doing the angular's real-time view updates magic
}
```

That's one way.

Comment: `scope.messages.push()` really sould be wrapped in `$apply`

Comment: use $apply() when you want to evaluate an expression. you can use $digest(). $apply() merely forces a $digest()

Comment: true, but `(..).scope().$apply(function() { scope.messages.push() })` was what the docs recommended last time I looked.

Comment: anyway you want. what $apply does is call a $digest after executing what needs to be applied. what really does the magic is $digest().

Comment: Yup, I just think you should edit one or the other into your answer which is why I commented.

Comment: @Noypi Thanks! I'll loook into it now...Also, how would I call a factory from function? I have a factory named 'principal' which has some user information I'd like to use...

Comment: Is it a directive factory or what factory? normally providers use this. from providers $get property

Comment: i think you really wanted to configure your service. use providers. if you want to tweak existing services, use $decorators.

Comment: @Noypi working like a charm. Thank you sir. I will look into providers and decorators