# AngularJS : On POST reload and show flash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, flash, express

I have converted one of my modals to angular.  Earlier I was submitting modal using:

`<form role="form" action="/home" method="post">`

and on controller side(ExpreessJS) I used following two lines to 1) show a success flash 2) reload the current page after various DB transactions have happened successfully so that current page reloads and appropriate success flash is poped up.

```
Route looks like this:
app.post('/home',someController.someMethod); 

req.flash('success', 'Successful');
res.redirect(req.headers.referer);
```

Now, with angular I have to do something like this on the same controller, where `data` is the `JSON` containing `form` variables:

```
$http.post('/home',data);
```

In my first method(without Angular), the flash is shown and page reloads.But with angular neither of event happens.

How to achieve the same functionality or behavior when POSTing using angular?

Comment: What is the question and what problems are you having achieving goal?

Comment: Made some edits. Hope that clarifies further.

Comment: You need to return a response instead and handle response in `$http` callback. Standard ajax pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload / refresh model data from the server programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693815/how-to-reload-refresh-model-data-from-the-server-programmatically)