# How to fire a scoped function from a .jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

I have a function called load in a .js file. :

```
$scope.load = function(id){

    alert(id);
};
```

This file is imported via a .jsp file and I'm attempting to call this function from this page :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function ($scope) {

        $scope.load('76348')


    });
```

The controller is defined within a div element :

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">

</div>
```

But I receive this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'showLinks'
```

I think a new $scope is being created since the method is not being found ? Is there a mechanism for accessing the $scope from the .jsp page ? I just want to fire the angularjs method on page load so any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: can you give source of $scope.load function ?

Comment: @Vlad Nikitin question updated now. thanks

Comment: in chrome dev tools in sources tab you can make it enable to stop on uncaught exceptions. Then you can watch the stack-trace and go through it and find the place where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got an ng-controller on your body, you'd use

`angular.element('body').scope().load(76348);`

But I should stress that this is a really bad idea. This is not jQuery. You really shouldn't access scopes like this ever because it breaks encapsulation, adds confusion to your app, and goes against best practices.

Comment: the controller is defined as part of a div, ive updated the question. Does this mean I need to assign an id to this div and use something like angular.element('MyControllerDivId').scope().load(76348);

Comment: So I named my div "mydiv" and to get the scope I used : var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("mydiv")).scope(); But perhaps this is a bad practice ? The answer by fallwind in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function led me to this.

Comment: Yes, or just `angular.element('#mydiv')` but this is all bad practice. You should never do any of this.