# AngularJS : Watch for class change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

Any ideas why angular watch did not work when class is added with jquery timeout function. The idea is that when jquery is fored to change class: angular to catch that new class. Working example in fiddle. When you scroll down you will see catched changing of class
Solved: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11kyd4to/)

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="holder">
        <div class="pusher"></div>
        <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="ui sticky gar" ng-repeat="friend in friends" add-remove-class>{{friend.name}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
       <div class="pusher"></div>
        <div class="pusher"></div>
        <div class="ui sticky" id="gar" add-remove-class>Garrrrr</div>
    </div>
    <p class="footer" ng-class="wohooOrNoo">footer</p>
</div>



 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $('#gar').sticky();
        $('gar').sticky();

       $scope.friends = [
      {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
      {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
      {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    ]
    });

    myApp.directive('addRemoveClass', function () {
        return {
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {

                // create an observer instance
                var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (element.hasClass('fixed')) {
                            alert("wee");
                        }
                    });
                });

                // configuration of the observer:
                var config = {
                    attributes: true
                };

                // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
                var node = element.get(0);
                observer.observe(node, config);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: element can not be watched like this.

Comment: My purpose is: if element has class to fire a function

Comment: @ngLover thx a lot. can you vote up my question

Answer (score 2):

No directive need for that in your context. just use **ng-class** in angular
[**Docs for ngClass**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
      <span id="zzz" ng-click="toggleClass()" ng-class="{'rouge': toggle, green : !toggle}">Coucou</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

angular:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
         setTimeout(function() {
         $('#zzz').addClass('rouge');
       }, 2000);
      $scope.toggle = false;
      $scope.toggleClass = function() {
          $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
      }
  })
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/11kyd4to/3/)

Comment: My purpose is: if element has class to fire a function, but 10x anyway

Comment: and I do not want to see green at beggining

Comment: @TeodorKolev - Have you look at the fiddle?

Comment: This is away from my point. I want to $watch for class. and if that class appears to fun a some function

Comment: @TeodorKolev - Sorry Your question is unClear. Ask anybody

Comment: I am pointing that $scope.$watch did not catch class changes. What is unclear?

Comment: can you vote my question, I have vote that answer for best

Answer (score 1):

While it is recommended to initiate changes from angular side, so angular will know what is happening, it is understandable sometimes you need to initiate from outside.

In this case angular `$watch` won't work because the change is not made within angular itself. You need to access the element scope and call `scope.$apply` manually from outside.

Please refer to: [AngularJS access scope from outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15425015/5039495)