# Share Angular Expression with onclick Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let me try explaining things again. I have an app running in a javascript framework on Node.js w/ Bootstrap. In one of the bootstrap panels I embedded an Angular Elasticsearch search client. Here's some code that displays the results:

```
<section class='results'><article class='result' ng-repeat='result in results track by $id(result)' /><div id="addThisInfo" ng-repeat='ng-repeat='result in results track by $id(result)' style="display: none;"> {{$id}},{{result.code}},{{result.expression}},{{result.source}}</div>Code:{{result.code}}<br>Description: {{result.expression}}<br>div ng-if='result.source ==4'> Type: Source 1</div><div ng-if='result.source ==10'> Type: Source 2</div></article> </section>
```

There are 5 results per page.

Note that the only portion of this app written in Angular is this search mechanism.

Ultimately I want the user to be able to click on either the text of the desired result or click on a button that would add their choices to a separate table.

Here's how it works rignt now.  When I click on any of the 5 results per page it invokes this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var packy = document.getElementById("addThisInfo").innerHTML; //div above
  addInfo(packy);
  });
```

It doesn't matter which ever one of the results I click, it always sends the "first" result of the active page.  Even though the div "addThisInfo" has been repeated and is part of the result, it doesn't

The web socket call looks something like this:

```
{"params":"0ij,I77.812ZZ,"Full Expression","100"}
```

I'm not having any luck uploading an image of the Inspect Element.  But there you can see that all of the data is there.

I'd like to schedule a http://join.me session with someone so I could show you how it's currently working.  Help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Angular *is* javascript. You need to give a lot more information about your problem, it doesn't make much sense as is. How do we know what `addInfo()` is, for instance.

Comment: Javascript should be friendlier to Javascript? Your question doesn't make much sense without substance.

Comment: Yes, it's JS, but sharing the variables are tricky.  I can declare a variable in JS and add it to my addInfo(var) very easily.  I can't seem to get the Angular vars to be recognized in JS.

Comment: What do you mean by "Keep it JS"? Inline event handlers were frowned upon because you were forced to have functions at global scope, but AngularJS keeps those functions properly scoped. There is nothing wrong with using ng-click if you're already using the AngularJS framework.

Comment: If Javascript is Javascript then how do I get result.source into addInfo()?

Comment: Angular isn't a language.  Any "Angular vars" are JavaScript vars.  You really need to provide more info on what it is exactly you tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: does `addInfo(result.source)` not work?

Comment: I'm basically using Angular for one search field with ElasticSearch only.  The rest of the framework is Javascript.

Comment: again, ***angular IS JavaScript***.

Comment: When I try addInfo(result.source) it says result isn't defined.

Comment: Please, update your question with the JavaScript or HTML where you are trying to call this function.

Comment: Claies, so, based on what you're saying how should I add the vars to my function then?

Comment: add your vars to *which* function? you haven't shown any code.

Comment: Claies, this is the source.  {{result.source}}, {{result.code}}, {{result.express}} all render on the page.  The onclick looks like this: <a href='#' onclick='addInFo()'>  I have other variables that have were originally declared in JS that I can easily pass like this: addInfo(id,name); But I can't seem to get source, code or expression to pass in...

Comment: I really want to help; quite a few people have downvoted the question because you don't seem to be able to communicate what it is you are trying to do, and it's very hard to try to ask questions through comments.  even in your latest comment, you haven't shown any HTML, you have simply shown 3 angular expressions with no context as to how these are defined in HTML, or how they relate to the function you are trying to call.

Comment: is the function part of your controller, defined on `$scope`, or defined in some other manner? is `result` an object on `$scope`?  is it an iteration of ng-repeat?

Comment: Claies, you asked me if addInfo(result.source) worked.  I told you that it responds that result is undefined.  That itself explains my problem.  It's not taking in variable like normal Javascript variables.

Comment: Yes.  As I stated, I can render {{result.source}} perfectly on the page.

Comment: no, that doesn't explain your problem; it's not possible to know *why* `ng-click="addInfo(result.source)"` wouldn't work, without seeing the ***full*** HTML that is in play, or knowing where/how `addInfo()` is defined.

Comment: You really need to learn javascript

Comment: and saying "I can't use ng-click, because I need to keep it JavaScript" doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: All of the Angular expressions work perfectly on the page.  I'm using output like this: Description: {{result.description}} and they render fine.  But when I try to pass them through a Javascript onclick() function it's not recogizing them.

Comment: where is the `<a>` defined? is it inside or outside the block of code where `ng-controller` is defined?

Comment: Deblaton, I have a pretty complex solution running on a javascript framwork.  I simply embedded Angular to work with a single search field with ElasticSearch and now I'm running into this challenge.  So dispense with the bull,. If it was so easy why don't I see you providing the fix?

Comment: at this point, all I can say is that until you can provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, the question is unanswerable.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  I really want to help, but you don't seem to want to help us understand your problem.  What you are describing isn't clear enough to continue.

Comment: and that comment "If it was so easy..." isn't helpful, because so far, you haven't described a situation that is common to angular, or a problem that makes sense.  Provided a fix for *what*, exactly? passing some random variables to some random function? you aren't even **passing** any variables to the function in your sample at all.

Comment: The <a> is defined inside.

Comment: Can you share more of your code get a better context.

Comment: adding angular on top of another app in the page just for one feature doesn't make sense either

Comment: Sure..putting it together

Comment: Charlietfil: What? Maybe not to you, but it totally works great.  Just need to pass the data through...

Comment: Faktor, I'll do better than that.  I'll share out my screen with you.

Answer (score 0):

why must you pass them individually? I'm unsure of what you're trying to accomplish, exactly, but I'd handle it something like this:

for the markup:

```
<button ng-click="addInfo(result)">
```

then in the controller

```
$scope.addInfo = function(result) {
    var foo = result.code,
        bar = result.source;

    etc...

}
```

Comment: I don't have to pass them individually, but I do need them to pass through onclick, not ng-click.

Comment: Let me ask the question like this; is it possible to invoke a "javascript onclick="addInfo()" function" from within an Angular app and pass Angular expressions through the function as parameters?

Comment: Yes but that's what ngclick does

Comment: [Another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function) about angular's $apply may lead you closer to an answer. I'm afraid I won't be of much further help until I understand why you must not use ng-click. you can use $apply to manipulate properties outside the context of their scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
Angular. directive('notNgClick',  function () { return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        scope: {
            values: '&' 
        }, 
        link: function (scope,elem, attr) {
           elem.addEventListener(function ()  {alert (scope.values.someValue ) } ) 
        } 
    } 
}
```