# Cannot set a scope inside document.bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to reset two scopes that defined before on an "esc" keyup event but it apparently does not work when I check out them. $document is defined on my controller's dependencies.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$document.bind('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        $scope.currentPage = false;
    }
});
```

I also tried the jQuery way. It doesn't work as well:

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        $scope.currentPage = false;
    }
});
```

What am I missing? What's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $scope.$apply(function() { ... }); to force the Angular digest cycle to run.

Your code will be:

```
$document.bind('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.currentPage = false;
    });
  }
});
```