# Access AngularJS $scope variable from simple JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This does not seems duplicate of

[AngularJS access scope from outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function), as I don't want this variable access on any click!

I have AngularJS code in my `Maincontroller.js` is

```
<div ng-controller = "Maincontroller">
   $scope.name = "Hello";
</div>
```

In My main.HTML file, I have JavaScript code where I want this `$scope.name` value:

```
 <html>
       <script>
          // But this seems not possible with {{ name}}
       </script>
 </html>
```

Is there any possibilities to access this `$scope` variable in JavaScript code?

Comment: wait you want to write javascript code in... javascript? Why don't just write it directly into the `<script>` tag instead of having them expressed?

Comment: How is it possible to directly use Name in script ? Its giving error by doing so !!

Comment: Forgetting anything to do with setting up the controller in JS, you know you're writting JavaScript code in a `div` right? You need to swap the code you have in your `<div>` and `<script>`

Comment: Javascript code in html is written with <script> </script> , whereas $scope.name is in my controller file !! Check updated

Comment: You have html code inside your .js file..? Look up on the first page of AngularJs documentation on how to create a controller.

Comment: why {{ name}} inside  <script> </script> ? in my opinion and understanding, you can just access directly to {{name}} inside html tag without needing the <script> tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS access scope from outside js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function)

Comment: Are you sure your code looks like that, or is [it more like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/etx32pmp/)

Comment: @George Exactly !! I want to access {{ name }} inside that script tag as mentioned there !!

Comment: Make a real controller, do whatever you want with `name` in it. That's basically the only answer you're going to get. You have things mixed up somehow. Your first code block makes no sense so it's unclear what your problem is, exactly. May I suggest the [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below code. What I did is I posted the name on the UI and with the help of id I fetched the value from the javascript code with the help of getElementById and innerHTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Maincontroller">
        Angualr Scope: <h1 id="name">{{name}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        A button to call a function from simple javascript function: <button onclick="getData()">Get Data: </button>        
    </div>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>

    <script>
        var getData = function(){
            var name = document.getElementById('name');
            console.log(name.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('Maincontroller', function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Hello";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```