# How to set ng-if value in protractor test case

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am having a two UI elements based on `ng-if` condition

```
<widget id="widget1" ng-if="vm.WidgetEnabled"
</widget>
<widget id="widget2" ng-if="!vm.WidgetEnabled"
</widget>
```

Controller makes REST API call which sets

```
WidgetEnabled = true
```

Now how can I test UI for

```
WidgetEnabled= false
```

scenario?

Any suggestions?

Can I set manually `WidgetEnabled = false` in protractor test case?

Comment: To test such cases you may want to mock backend with i.e. js backend, where you have full control on everything.

Answer (score 0):

As you do an e2e test scenario you typically would simulate the users actions, that would be required for the widget to be disabled (a button click which calls the REST API and disabled it, logging in as another user, who has other permissions or sth. like that). I would not recommend to change angular controller variables in protractor tests, because this is not the way e2e tests are intended to work.

Comment: But is that possible?

Comment: Technically it is possible. See some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424910/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-js-function/15425015

Comment: Thanks it looks promising, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mocking and mock the response of the REST API with `true` and `false` values. However ideally that should be a part of your unit tests and not e2e tests.

Comment: Problem is that API can return either true or false.