# Tap into angular app from non angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular in my browser addon.

I have created an app like this:

```
var myServices = [];
var ANG_APP = angular.module('mailtowebmails', [])
    .controller('BodyController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

        var MODULE = this;

        MODULE.reinit = function() {
            MODULE.myServices = myServices
        }
    }]);
```

After I populate/change the contents of the global `myServices` array I want angular to read in the updated one. Simply passing as reference does not work, is there somehow I can call `ANG_APP.BodyController.reinit()`?

Comment: This can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19198058/5157454

Comment: You can not invoke controller functions without `$scope`. `controller` functions and data is available only within `$scope`.

Comment: Very interesting @OriDrori thanks for it!