# assigning values to angular controller through javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to Angularjs as well as Javascript. Want to know how to pass some values to the angular controller. I have an external javascript function which contains the data and I want to use the value in the javascript functions defined inside the angularjs controller.

Please help me to get this done..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code/10508731#10508731

Comment: Consider my advice, please : Please play around a bit with plain JavaScript, maybe a month or a bit more, before taking a framework or an UI library. It will be really helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, in many cases you can just reference the object inside your Angular controller:

```
myObject.data();
```

You don't want to do this because then you are adding an undefined dependency to your controller, and that will cause trouble when trying to unit test your code.  I believe undefined dependencies can cause issues when it comes to code maintenance too.

You could also wrap your custom object in an Angular Service.  Something like this:

```
angularApp.factory('myCustomService', function(){
        return new myCustomObject();
    }
);
```

Then you can pass this object into the controllers:

```
function myController($scope,myCustomService) {}
```

I have used this when dealing with JavaScript code generated by WebORB.