# AngularJS doesnt "bootstrap" new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS app which (reduced to relevant parts) looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div id='container'>
        <div say-hello-to name="Frank">f</div>
        <div say-hello-to name="Billy">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the application works fine. Now, if after the angular bootstrapping process, I add a new dom element, which corresponds to a directive, it isn't interpreted. Note that the "Addition" is done by non-angularjs JavaScript Code.

```
<div say-hello-to name="Dusty">d</div>
```

it is just "dead" div.

JsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn34X/

The question is: How can I add a new DOM Element into the application and let AngularJS know that there is a new Element to be interpreted (I could easily point angularjs exactly to all inserted elements)

Cheers, and thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you have to add those elements in a non-angular js code?

Comment: if you are adding the element with jQuery you need to compile it first

Comment: @OmriAharon: yes, it needs to be non-angular code

Comment: @doodeec: compile how? do you have an example?

Comment: @iPirat have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Ul3XTt6NCfY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrieve the `$injector` service:

```
var $injector = angular.element(document.querySelector('#container')).injector();
```

Select the element:

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('[name="Dusty"]'));
```

Use the $injector service to retrieve the `$compile` service and link the element to the scope:

```
$injector.invoke(function ($compile) {    
  var scope = element.scope();
  $compile(element)(scope);
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/6n7xk/

Short explanation: [Call Angular JS from legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code/10508731#10508731)

Comment: As a follow-up: if REMOVING such an element using non-angular code, is it enough to do `angular.element(...).scope().$destroy()` or is there anything else to consider?