# How can I detect if an Angular app has been initialized from outside Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

While developing the [lift-ng](https://github.com/joescii/lift-ng) plugin, I have noticed [an issue](https://github.com/joescii/lift-ng/issues/1) where sometimes the server sends events via comet to the client prior to angular initialization.  This causes events to be silently missed by the application.  I would like to know if there is a way to detect if an app has been initialized, i.e. all controllers, services, directives, etc have been instantiated and hence all listeners are ready for events.  Because this is a plugin, I need to be able to do it without requiring the angular components to implement any code.  I can add a controller, service, or whatever to the app, but the solution cannot require that every component sends an event, for instance.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code

Comment: u know that `angular.js` is javascript right? javascript.

Comment: @true Yeah... I tagged it as JS.

Comment: @Jorg thanks for the tip.  That is precisely how I get those events to cross over into the angular world.  The problem is they can arrive before the app is initialized and the events are dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
try {
    angular.bootstrap(document)
} 
catch(e) {
    console.log(!!e.message.indexOf('btstrpd')) 
    //will log true if the error is of the type `btstrpd`, 
    //you can do whatever you want with it here.
}
```

If there is already an app bootstrapped, [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) will emit an error. [`btstrpd`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd) is the name of the error that means an app has already been bootstrapped.

This is simple enough, and I hope it works for your case, but if it doesn't ping me and I'll think of something more elaborate.

---

**Another approach:**

If you have some information about the modules, you can check the components have been bootstrapped using this:

`angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().has('$http')`

This finds where the `ng-app` attribute was used, then calls the initialized [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) instance, from which you can call `has` to see what providers have been initialized.

---

**Yet another approach:**

Instead of `angular.bootstrap` you can try `angular.module` without a second argument, which should retrieve the module if it has been loaded or emit an error.

```
try {
    angular.module('moduleName')
} 
catch(e) {
    console.log(!!e.message.indexOf('nomod')) 
    //will log true if the error is of the type `nomod`, 
    //you can do whatever you want with it here.
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting.  However, this could interfere with someone else's bootstrapping, right?  For instance, if the page has multiple apps which requires some special-handling.  Thanks for taking interest!

Comment: Cool, I'll play around with it and see how it goes!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  If my event calls `bootstrap` first, then the application fails to boot because it has already been bootstrapped on that element.

Comment: @joescii added a different approach

Comment: Nice. This gives me another idea.  Perhaps it is sufficient to check if `scope()` returns a defined object.  Due to the single-threaded spec of a browser, I assume that if that object returns then the whole app has been initialized.

Comment: @joescii well, it means something has been initialized. Could be just angular without modules too. If it works for you, that's great. Consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Based on some preliminary investigation, this approach I mentioned should work.  Thanks for setting me on the right path!