# Angular onsubmit for form

Tags: angularjs, forms

I need the functionality of the `onsubmit` attribute on a form - namely when I call this `onsubmit` function, it must return truthy in order for the form to post. However I would like to do this with an angular function call, along the lines of:

```
<form id="form-submit-canvas" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" onsubmit="{{FormSubmit.validate()}}" action="{{FormSubmit.SUBMIT_URL}}" novalidate>
```

However the above gives out errors about interpolation being used on `onsubmit`. I tried putting in `ng-submit` and it does not work since the `action` property I have set is overridden.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? That is a good place to start: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Yes I have. "Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain `action`...". So that doesn't appear to be the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it's still valid for you, but as I've been fighting the similar problem.

Following answer brought me to the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17769240/1581069

So, to sum up the steps required:

1. you should call pure javascript (angular-free one) in your `onsubmit`, like (please note: if you return false there => form won't be submited):

   ```
   <form id="form-submit-canvas" ... name="fooForm" onsubmit="return externalValidate();" ...
   ```
2. And implement the the method to hand-over to angular, like:

   ```
   function externalValidate(){
     return angular.element($("#form-submit-canvas")).scope().validate();
   }
   ```

   - where your `validate()` method should be just one you referred to previously (implemented in your angular controller).
   - and `externalValidate()` should be implemented outside of any angular-specific component.
3. Moreover make sure sure to return correct result from the `validate()` method (to prevent form submission). Maybe something like:

   ```
   $scope.validate = function () {
     // TODO implement whatever magic you need prior to submission

     return $scope.fooForm.$valid;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `ng-submit` attribute instead of `onsubmit`. Related advise: Many attributes are not supported by Angular. You should find the `ng-` equivalent of the attribute you want to use to get Angular to react to them properly.

Example:

```
<form id="form-submit-canvas" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" ng-submit="validate()" novalidate>
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Where the `validate()` method in `ng-submit` is a method declared on your `$scope`.

Here is a related tutorial: [AngularJS Tutorial (`ng-submit`)](http://learnwebtutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial-submitting-form-ng-submit)

Answer (score 1):

Well I know this could help somebody looking for how to use the submit form action in Angular. I'm working with Angular 13 and this is how we can capture the submit action:

```
<form [formGroup]="formData" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <button type="submit">Click here!</button>
</form>
```

[The reference is here](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission)

Comment: What if the form element has an `action` attribute? I want to post to that URL and being notified if this succeeds. But it seems that `action` is ignored when I introduce Angular forms?

Answer (score -1):

> use onsubmit="return angular.element(this).scope().validate();" to use
> angular validate funcation.

```
    <form id="form-submit-canvas" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" onsubmit="return angular.element(this).scope().validate();" >
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```