# Function is not defined inside controller, angularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, function, controller

I am trying to execute a function after a video ends, the function is inside an angular controller. The function is called, but I get an error stating:

```
ReferenceError: postVendor is not defined
```

Here is the calling javascript:

```
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var api = flowplayer();
            api.bind("finish", function (e, api) {
                var data = "true";
                var url = "someurlhere";
                postVendor(url, data);
            });
        });
```

and here is my module/controller (same file):

```
var registrationModule = angular.module('registrationModule', []);

registrationModule.controller("vendorCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.postVendor = function (url, data) {
        $http.post(url, data).success(function (data) { console.log(data) }).error(function (data) { console.log(data)  });
    };

});
```

in my html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="registrationModule">

<body ng-controller="vendorCtrl">
```

I am using angular 1.2.25.

Any ideas on how to get the function called properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please make sure that jQuery is loaded before angular.js

2.Make sure that your vendorCtrl return $scope.postVendor (you can do that by adding) :

```
  return {
    postVendor : $scope.postVendor 

  };
```

Please see example

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    
     
     angular.element('#angularController').controller().doSomthing("Hello ", "from jquery")
  
  });


var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.doSomthing = function(a,b){
    alert(a+b);
  };
  
  
  
 return {
    doSomthing: $scope.doSomthing
    
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app"  >
  <div  id="angularController" ng-controller="firstCtrl">

      </div>
</body>
```

That should helps

```
  $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var api = flowplayer();
        api.bind("finish", function (e, api) {
            var data = "true";
            var url = "someurlhere";
           angular.element('body').controller().postVendor(url, data);
        });
    });
```

for more info please see here [Call Angular JS from legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code)

Comment: thanks, I was just trying variations of this but get: `Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!`