# Call angular js method by silverlight control

Tags: c#, angularjs, silverlight

I've my Web page structured with AngularJs that hosting a Silverlight Control.  Now I need to call a function placed in a controller angular from silverlight. This is my controller angular code sample:

```
    var myModule= angular.module('MyModule', []);

    myModule.controller('MainController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

        var _self = this;
        _self.testMethodForSilverlight = function (message)
        {
            alert("message: " + message);
        }; 
}]);
```

and this is the code in my Silverlight viewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    { 
      public void CallAngularMethod()
      {
           HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("testMethodForSilverlight ", new[] { "Testing" });
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately when I call the method the error returned is ("Failed to invoke: testMethodForSilverlight" ). 
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing your custom Javascript code and do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function callAngularFunc(message) {
    angular.element($("#elementID")).scope().testMethodForSilverlight(message);
 }
</script>
```

Here, elementID will be the DOM element that the angular controller is bound to.

There is more info related accessing angular data from outside [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code).

Then, in your silverlight code, make the call like this

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    { 
      public void CallAngularMethod()
      {
           HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("callAngularFunc", new[] { "Testing" });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. I've also found a less angular solution. You can declare a method without '$scope' or without 'this' and this method will be global. But your solution is better. Thanks you very much