# How to access $scope from legacy code in AngularJS >= 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before AngularJS 1.3 there was a simple method of doing this (`angular.element(node).scope()`) but now with `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` this way of accessing scope is no longer working. Is there another simple solution?

Comment: What's the use case for needing to access scope by element? Perhaps need a directive to do the reverse. Please show some code

Comment: I need to access angular app from legacy JavaScript code. This is the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code but with angular 1.3

Comment: More details of what your legacy code is doing would help if you are wanting a workaround