# Facebook Login API in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, facebook-authentication

I am using the facebook authentication API v2.8 in an angularJs application mostly following the document https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/facebook-authentication-in-your-angularjs-web-app/. I have put the authentication related code in a service. Now, i want to use the facebook login button inside a component like -

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="$ctrl.checkLoginState()">
</fb:login-button>
```

I intend to call the authentication service from the method  `$ctrl.checkLoginState` defined inside my component controller, but I am getting an uncaught reference error -

> sdk.js:89 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ctrl is not defined(…).

Any ideas to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to find a solution to this following Misko's suggestion on [Call Angular JS from legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490570/call-angular-js-from-legacy-code).

Created a javascript method to be invoked after the onlogin event is fired, and then invoked the angular component controller function explicitly like this -

```
angular.element($("#elementId")).scope().$ctrl.checkLoginState();
```

From there I can call my service.